# I can't save string variables inside a string variable during a PHPl oop

Tags: php

Hello guys I have the following problem where a fix in php

```html
?php
  $fruits = array ("Apple", "Blackberry", "Strawberry");
  $tablerows = "";
   foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) {
       $rows = ""; 
       $rows = '<tr>
                    <td>'.$value.'</td>
                </tr>';
       $tablerows = $rows;
  }
  echo  $tablerows;
?>
```

this is the result

```html
<tr>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
</tr>
```

and what I expect should be like this

```html
<tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Blackberry</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
</tr>
```

Anyone who can help me solve this problem would be very grateful.

Comment: Use `.=` not `=`. to append to a string.

Comment: There's no need for `$rows = "";` since you overwrite it on the next line.

Comment: Please do not use stacksnippet formatting for server-side code.

Comment: Friend thank you very much it works in one, you are the best